# Which Ubuntu version would i use?

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, versions

I am a programmer, i have a old laptop with the same configuration as below: cpu Core 2 duo Intel T5870 2GHz, Ram 1GB. Can i use Ubuntu version for my work ? Thanks for help!

Comment: Your CPU is OK, but you will need more RAM to use a browser. But It will boot 18.04 Ubuntu with 1 GB RAM.

Comment: From my personal experience I can recommend Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS. It works on systems with 2 Gb of RAM. But do not forget to buy more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.lubuntu.net/lubuntu_installation_on_old_computers.html, the minimum requirements for Lubuntu 18.04 is 1 GB of RAM. You should use Lubuntu, here is a link to the download page for Lubuntu: https://lubuntu.net/downloads/

Lubuntu is a lighter version of Ubuntu, which uses the LXDE desktop environment, rather than GNOME.